# CGGradient Not Displaying Correctly on iPad 1 and 2

Tags: ios, ipad, gradient, quartz-graphics

I have been experimenting with creating my own gradients for the UI in my iOS app. I first used a CAGradientLayer but I was disappointed with the "stepped" look so I have been trying out CGGradient.

```
   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {

        CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGGradientRef skyGradient;
        CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;
        size_t num_locations = 3;
        CGFloat locations[3] = { 0.0, .5, 1.0 };
        CGFloat components[12] = { .106, .73,  .93333, 1.,
                                  0.0,  0.0 , 1.0,     1., 
                                   .106, .73,  .93333, 1. };

        rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        skyGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

        CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
        CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
        CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMaxY(currentBounds));
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, skyGradient, topLeft, bottomRight, 0);

        CGGradientRelease(skyGradient);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace); 

    }
```

I am having an issue with the Gradient displaying correctly. I have three iPads—one for each generation. The gradient looks right on the iPad 3 but not on the iPad 1 or 2. This is really strange. I was going to take a screenshot and post the two differences but even more strange, the screenshot looks the same (and yes, the brightness is the same on both).

The colors seem really washed out on the older iPads. I know the iPad 3 is a retina display, but I think it must be something more than that.

[image: Not a great picture, but you can still see a drastic difference.]

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code and not just the screen? What happens if you render the same gradient in an image editor on your Mac and display the exact same image on both devices side by side?

Comment: Good thinking, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I did as you suggested and used an image from Illustrator with the exact same gradient settings. Just as before, the iPad 3 looks the same (or similar) to my Cinema Display for color. The other two iPad's and my iPhone 4 aren't even close. So I am a little worried as to how I can achieve a consistent looking UI over multiple devices. Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about it. There is no way for the user to calibrate their device to the current lighting conditions so you can never guarantee accurate colors for all cases. As long as your app looks the same relative to other apps on the same device you should be fine

Comment: Thanks David. So just wondering what to do with this question now. Because your replies have been in the form of comments, I can't accept them as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question, as David Rönnqvist pointed out, is that these devices simply don't display color the same way. There is not a simple solution to this, and perhaps a solution would be over kill.